# Display object name in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class, mandelbrot

I'm working on a project where I need to make an interactive windows forms application displaying the mandelbrot set. I now want to implement a drop down list on this window, where you can choose between different pictures of the mandelbrot set. I have made a class for the settings for these pictures:

```
public class Mandelpoint
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double s;
    public string name;

    public Mandelpoint(double x, double y, double s, string name)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.s = s;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and I have the following drop down menu:

```
presets = new ComboBox();
presets.Size = new Size(150, 20);
presets.Location = new Point(250, 20);
this.Controls.Add(presets);

presets.Items.Add(new Mandelpoint(0, 0, 0.01, "standard"));
```

as you can see, I want the items in the `combobox` to be `Mandelpoints`. When I open the form, the dropdownlist is shown like this:

[image]

is there a way, by for example defining some sort of `MandelpointToString` method in the `Mandelpoint` class, that the Mandelpoints are displayed as their name in the drop down list? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `ToString` method.

```
public class Mandelpoint
{
    public override string ToString()
        => name;
}
```

You can also set the `DisplayMember` of the combobox.

```
public class Mandelpoint
{
    public string Name => name;
}

presets.DisplayMember = "Name"
```